# rospy rqt - shutdown?

Tags: ros, rospy, plugin, rqt, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Python%20Plugin) asks to shutdown publishers and subscribers in the overloaded shutdown_plugin method but doesn't explain how this is done. I couldn't find any advice on how to shutdown a publisher and unsubscribe a subscriber. Could anyone guide me? Thanks

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163011/rospy-rqt---shutdown?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Example of **stopping `Subscriber` in rqt plugin in `rospy`**

In `shutdown_plugin` you can do basically whichever way you usually do to finish your ROS process.

I'll take `rqt_plot` as an example. In a class derived from `rqt_gui_py.plugin` (which I'm sure you've already made in your case), [there's `shutdown_plugin` defined as](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/c7258ed28894e7830a74cf5b80e90ffd15cc3ae2/rqt_plot/src/rqt_plot/plot.py#L189):

```
def shutdown_plugin(self):
    self._widget.clean_up_subscribers()
```

Then the method called above is defined [here in a widget class](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/2c0593781da018fa247a0ae45b8d99c64dfce2f7/rqt_plot/src/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py#L224)

```
def clean_up_subscribers(self):
    for topic_name, rosdata in self._rosdata.items():
        rosdata.close()
        self.data_plot.remove_curve(topic_name)
    :
```

`rosdata.close()` is defined [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/2c0593781da018fa247a0ae45b8d99c64dfce2f7/rqt_plot/src/rqt_plot/rosplot.py#L112) that internally calls `rospy.Subscriber.unregister`.

This isn't the simplest example but you should get the idea.

---

(**Update**) Example of **stopping Publisher in rqt plugin in rospy**

There aren't many rqt plugins out there that explicitly stop publishing topics, but looks like `rqt_bag` does in the following sequence (indices at the beginning of each line are linking to the actual code):

[1](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/f455dd6a1b4154d4e54f3bacc1ad816a133ac5e7/rqt_bag/src/rqt_bag/bag.py#L72)

```
def shutdown_plugin(self):
    self._widget.shutdown_all()
```

[2](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/f455dd6a1b4154d4e54f3bacc1ad816a133ac5e7/rqt_bag/src/rqt_bag/bag_widget.py#L297)

```
def shutdown_all(self):
    self._timeline.handle_close()
```

[3](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/f455dd6a1b4154d4e54f3bacc1ad816a133ac5e7/rqt_bag/src/rqt_bag/bag_timeline.py#L114)

```
def handle_close(self):
    :
    for topic in self._get_topics():
        self.stop_publishing(topic)
        self._message_loaders[topic].stop()
    :
```

[4](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/f455dd6a1b4154d4e54f3bacc1ad816a133ac5e7/rqt_bag/src/rqt_bag/bag_timeline.py#L487)

```
def stop_publishing(self, topic):
    if not self._player:
        return False

    self._player.stop_publishing(topic)
```

And [5](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/f455dd6a1b4154d4e54f3bacc1ad816a133ac5e7/rqt_bag/src/rqt_bag/player.py#L66)

```
    :
    if topic in self._publishers:
        self._publishers[topic].unregister()
        del self._publishers[topic]
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-08**:
My question more relates to the actual shutdown of publishers and subscribers than the plugin. I should have made that clearer. You answered on how to shutdown a subscriber. Is it the same for publishers?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-09**:
I added my finding about publisher to my answer.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-09**:
Thanks a lot. Looks like it's a bit more complex to shutdown a publisher... is it actually really necessary?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-09**:
Answer should be "no"; I just referred to the entire steps only because I have no experience in stopping publisher with rqt python plugin. In essence you should just be able to stop by calling `unregister`.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-09**:
Alright, I'll do it by just calling unregister. It basically shouldn't be that much of an issue in my config anyway. So... thanks a lot!